# Are Python's map and filter really so ridiculously fast or are my measurements wrong?

Tags: python, numpy

I do some speed tests for operations on vectors/lists. Suprisingly, `map` and `filter` seem to beat `numpy` by a factor of 5-10x. See the following short code sample with times given (Full code below.):

```
n = 10000000
a = np.random.rand(n)
b = np.random.rand(n)
c = a + b # time = 0.07 s
d = a[a < 0.3] # time = 0.09 s

a = [random.random() for x in range(0, n, 1)]
b = [random.random() for x in range(0, n, 1)]
c = map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b) # time = 0.006s
d = filter(lambda e: e < 0.3, a) # time = 0.001s
```

Is it really possible that `map` and `filter` are that much faster than the `numpy` operations? Or are my measurements flawed? You can see the full code below:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random

class StopWatch:

    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str
        self.t = time.time()

    def stop(self):
        t = time.time()
        print("time = " + str(t - self.t) + " s for " + self.str)

n = 10000000
a = np.random.rand(n)
b = np.random.rand(n)

sw = StopWatch('numpy')
c = a + b
sw.stop()

sw = StopWatch('numpy')
d = a[a < 0.3]
sw.stop()

a = [random.random() for x in range(0, n, 1)]
b = [random.random() for x in range(0, n, 1)]

sw = StopWatch('list')
c = map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b)
sw.stop()

sw = StopWatch('list')
d = filter(lambda e: e < 0.3, a)
sw.stop()
```

If my measurements are correct, WHY is it that much faster?

Comment: What version of Python? Note that `map` and `filter` are lazy (returning iterators) in Python 3. So yes, your measurements are flawed: the `map` and `filter` versions aren't actually doing any computation.

Comment: `c = map(...)` doesn't actually do much. For an equal comparison, you need to *consume* the iterator.

Comment: Running your code in python2 gives opposite results: list is 20 times slower than numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that `c = map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b)` is actually not calculated. In python 3, `map` and `filter` are evaluated lazy, and therefore not before they have to be evaluated.

You can verify this by adding a `list(c)` before you stop the timer, though this might affect the time a little more for the list creation.

Comment: You can't print the last element of an iterator, that doesn't make any sense. For example: `TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`